# Can I install the vanilla MATE desktop environment alongside the Ubuntu MATE Remix desktop environment (15.04 Vivid Vervet)?

Tags: software-installation, mate

I have installed the Ubuntu MATE Remix desktop environment on Ubuntu 15.04 (Please note I have a regular Ubuntu installation with the desktop environment on it, not the Ubuntu MATE flavor of Ubuntu). I use this as my main desktop environment. Will installing the [vannila MATE desktop environment](http://mate-desktop.org/) (to try it out) break my Ubuntu MATE Remix installation?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple DE's at the same time, and you will be able to choose one of them when you boot Ubuntu. To do this, run the following commands in a terminal emulator (Ctrl+Alt+T):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/trusty-mate
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

The "--no-install-recommends" attribute is very important in this process. It tells APT not to overwrite anything. After all this process ends, you can log out your current session and choose other DE at the login screen (above your user icon, near the hour applet).

Comment: Since Ubuntu MATE is simply called "MATE" on the lock screen, I was wondering if that might mess things up. Also, your instructions are for Ubuntu 14.04, not 15.04, and for installing the Ubuntu MATE desktop, not the vanilla MATE one.  This may confuse other Ask Ubuntu users.